# Why $Gal(GF(p^n)/GF(p))\equiv U(p^{n-1})$ is not true $?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

It  is  already  proved that

$1) \ \ $ $$Gal(GF(p^n)/GF(p))\equiv \mathbb Z_n$$

and  $GF(p^n)$  is the  splitting  field  of  $x^{p^n}-x=x(x^{p^{n-1}}-1)$  over $GF(p)$.

Now  the  second  one  comes  as

$2)\ \ $ "$F$  is  a field  and  $E=F(\alpha )$  where  $\alpha $  is  a  primitive  $n$th   root  of $1$. Then $Gal(E/F)$  is  isomorphic to  a  subgroup  of  $U(n)$."

But  if  we take  a  field  $F$  and  the  splitting  field, $E$,  of  $x^n -1$  over  it  then the  Galois group $Gal(E/F)$  isomorphic  to  a  subgroup  of  $U(n)$.

Why  this  happens $?$  I  have   gone  through  both  the  proofs  and  step  by  step  they  are  clear  but  the  whole picture  is  confusing. In  the  second  case  I  can  take  $F=\mathbb Z_p$. Then  using  this  result  in  the  first  one,  considering  the  power  of  $x$  in  the  equation , I  get  that  the  Galois  group  is  isomorphic  to a  subgroup  of  $U(p^{n-1})$.

In  both  the  proofs,  every  non zero  element  of  the  basis has  the  for $\alpha ^k$ for  some  integer  $k$  and  the  map  defined $$\sigma : Gal(./.)\rightarrow \mathbb Z_n$$ is  $$\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha^k$$  for  some  $k$. But next  to  this,  in  the  second  proof, it  requires **$k$**  to  be  relatively  prime  to  **$n$**  as  $\sigma$  has  to  be  an  automorphism  over $<\alpha>$  and  hence  comes  $U(n)$  into  the  picture.

Then  in  the  first  proof  also I  could  say $\sigma$  had  to  map  $\alpha$  to  $\alpha^i$  where  $i$  is  relatively  prime  to  $p^{n-1}$ and  relate  it  to  a  subgroup  of  $U(p^{n-1})$ but  then  again , the map $$\alpha\mapsto \alpha^p$$  is  found  to  have  order  $n$  and  it  is  cyclic.

But  my  question  is,  in  the  second  theorem  also,  for  any $i$  s.t.  $(i,n)=1$ would  not  order  of  $$\alpha \mapsto \alpha^i$$  be  $n$  $?$. Then  why  is  this  not  cyclic  and  isomorphic  to  $\mathbb Z_n$  $?$

I  think  I  am  misunderstanding  something  seriously  and  this  post  is  very  clumsy, I  know, apologies  for  that. Please explain  this  to  me.

Thanks.

Comment: By $U\left(n\right)$ do you mean the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ ? And by $\mathbb{Z}_n$ do you mean $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg : Yes  . .

Comment: The multiplicative group of $GF(p^n)$ is cyclic of order $p^n-1$. IOW a primitive element $\alpha$ is a root of unity of order $p^n-1$. And the coset of $p$ generates a cyclic subgroup of order $n$ inside $U(p^n-1)$, so these facts fit together nicely. How did you end up with $U(p^{n-1})$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$x^{p^n}-x=x(x^{p^n-1}-1)\neq x(x^{p^{n-1}}-1).$$